Rename colums for each table in select statement in sparksql
I have to join several tables which has similar column names in them. When I run the sql, it says duplicate column is not allowed. Just to explain the problem, i have created a pseudo query below
select a.*, b.* 
    from tableA as a, tableB as b
        where a.key = b.key

tableA
------
key myCol1

tableB
key myCol1

I am running sparksql from DBVisalizer 13. The error i get is
"java.lang.IllegalStateException: Duplicate key file_date (attempted merging values 1 and 170) -> See Tools->Debug Window and the Error Log for details) "
Is there a way to rename all columns with a prefix for each table (like a_myCol1 and b_myCol1) in sparksql ?

I think in DBVisalizer it is not possible. you can do this using spark with scala or python.
